# CakePHP frontpage without index.php has error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm getting an error when I try to open test.domain.com/ if I add index.php (test.domain.com/index.php) it works and subpage test.domain.com/shop also works without index.php between the domain and path (test.domain.com/index.php/shop)
I'm trying to set it up on a shared hosting as a subdomain for testing purpose.
I already tried different RewriteBase rules in htaccess without success.

Error notice:

```
class AppController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'App';


    function webroot() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your shared host, do you know if .htaccess files are enabled ( AllowOverride should be set on your vhost) It sounds like the rewrite rules are not being loaded.

If this is the case, [then read this for information on how to debug this...](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/BBBThunda/2010/02/25/troubleshooting-cakephp-installation-issues-related-to-apache-2-mod_rewrite-for-beginners)

If this is the case and you can't get your shared host to enable .htaccess, [check out this link for information about running cake without mod_rewrite](http://wwdj.wijndaele.com/getting-started-with-cakephp-without-mod_rewrite/)

Comment: rather spend the time getting it working. 99% of hosts should have .htaccess files working

Comment: Thanks. htaccess is working only the default path is with error. I have config/routes.php set Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'user_designs', 'action' => 'home')); but it is not loading that controller action. If I add /index.php it loads correctly. The views/layouts/default.ctp is rendered and there I get 
Error: The action webroot is not defined in controller AppController

Error: Create AppController::webroot() in file: app/controllers/app_controller.php
I don't know why is it requesting that action.